# Duplicate a SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint

Is there a way to easily duplicate a SharePoint list code wise?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Judging from the SharePoint tag, I'm assuming you meant to ask "How do I copy a SharePoint list (SPList) programmatically?"
Without testing it (or even trying to compile it), I would do something like:

```
SPWeb web; /* add code to initialize to current web */
SPList sourceList = web.Lists["nameOfSourceList"];
sourceList.SaveAsTemplate("templateFNM.stp", "tempList", "tempListDescription", 
                          true /* include list content */);
SPListTemplate template = web.ListTemplates["tempList"];
web.Lists.Add("newListName", "newListDescription", template);
web.Update();
SPList newList = web.Lists["newListName"];
```

Also, [here's](http://www.sharepointblogs.com/sajana/archive/2008/07/06/saving-a-custon-list-template-and-uploading-it-to-another-site-programmatically.aspx) a link to a blog post that achieves the same accross web applications.

And finally a word of advice: you'll get better search results if you use "programmatically" instead of "code wise".

Hope this helps.